# How to start retraining of Tensorflow seq2seq model from last saved state?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tensorflow

I am completely new to tensorflow and I am using their seq2seq translate example. I looked at the code in translate.py and the training is done in an infinite loop which saves checkpoints in the file translate.ckpt every now and then.

So, if I stop training and want to restart it later from the last saved state, how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initiating variables in a session, you need to restore variables  from file:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Restore variables from disk.
  saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model restored.")
  # Do some work with the model
```

Notice that your model is just a values of variables. In order to restore them, you need a graph with same variable names. And probably operations that you need to perform in order to calculate results.

Read more about it here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/variables/index.html#restoring-variables

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out so thought I should answer it. The seq2seq example does this by default. If you stop the training loop and then restart it, it looks for the saved checkpoints and restarts training from where it left off last time.